# AWS service discovery for EC2 instances?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, http-proxy, squid, service-discovery

I started few nano instances of EC2 (ubuntu without container) with installed Squid Proxy (http://www.squid-cache.org/).

I sometimes need to add additional instances for some period, so the solution should be ready for dynamic config.

Is there any AWS service discovery solution?

I need to have access to these proxies and service discovery from outside of AWS (so I need to read public IPs of EC2 instances with proxies).

Answer (score 0):

There is **not out-of-the box solution** for registering public ip of instances with a Route53 record. You have to develop **custom solution** for that, if you don't want to front your instance with a load balancer (how it should be done in the first place). Nevertheless, AWS explains how you can develop such a solution in:

- [Building a Dynamic DNS for Route 53 using CloudWatch Events and Lambda](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/compute/building-a-dynamic-dns-for-route-53-using-cloudwatch-events-and-lambda/)

Comment: How do you think about AWS Cloud Map?

Comment: @bmilczarek I'm not sure if cloud map is for use only within AWS, or you can access discovered instances from outside of AWS.